# Shrink-wrapping is leaving a visible white line when applied onto object

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm applying shrink-wrapping modifier and data transfer to my object. The outer shrink-wrap works well, but the inner part of the object has a hard line which shows.

The original object where the yellow arrow is pointing has a smooth transition, but when applied the object where the blue arrows are pointing has the white hardish line visible.

[image]

Comment: Have you got the weights in the vertex group correct for those verts?

Comment: Yes in the vertex weights, it shows each vertex going from 1. 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2

Comment: Here's the file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=akrQ7Lkk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/akrQ7Lkk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got too many loops causing a linear falloff, also put your sub-d mod after the shrinkwrap.
[image]

Here I've removed 2 off the loops, then assigned the weights from outer to inner as 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25
[image]
[image]

The next loop up you can scale in a little to get a better look.

Also, turn off outline in your overlay settings to get a better look at what's going on.

Also, also... Please consider replacing that top face with a gridfill 
[image]

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! 

I followed and got a matching result, much smoother transition. 


https://ibb.co/MGXgwvM

Comment: You're welcome  Glad to see it worked out for you